# Filter gmails using timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

Am new dabbling with Google Apps Script; would like to ask if I'm in the right direction, and how to I manipulate time within the script.

I'm struggling in trying to maniuplate time values in Google App Script, basically I am able to pull the timestamp of each email sent, but I only want to paste into the spreadsheet email information that were recent, e.g. within 30minutes from script run time. This is to avoid pulling duplicate information.

Not sure if there is a currentTime() function here, or I have to create a new Date() object and do some calculations from there. Tried a few variations and nothing seemed to work proper.

Would appreciate any help in getting towards the right direction in doing this thank you!

```
function getDetails(){
  var DEST_URL = "SHEET_URL"; //redacted for sensitivity
  var DEST_SHEETNAME = "Test";
  
  var destss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(DEST_URL);
  var destSheet = destss.getSheetByName(DEST_SHEETNAME);
  
  var threads = GmailApp.search("FILTERS"); //filter settings redacted for sensitivity

  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();  
    for(var j =0; j < 1; j++){ //only take first message in thread
      var message = messages[j];
      var subject = message.getSubject() ;
      var sentTimeStamp = message.getDate();

      if(sentTimeStamp is within last 30minutes as of script run time){ //this is where i need help
          var delimitString = subject.split("is sent");
          var detailName = delimitString[0];

          var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
          destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1).setValue(detailName);
          destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,2),setValue(sentTimeStamp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Another idea would be to query for emails that you received the last 30 minutes.

**Explanation:**

You can get the emails that you received the last 30 minutes ago as a query in the `GmailApp.search` function. See this [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) to see what filters you can use.

This will get the last emails with keyword "FILTERS" that you received the last 30 minutes.

```
var ThirtyMinutesAgo = new Date(); 
ThirtyMinutesAgo.setMinutes(ThirtyMinutesAgo.getMinutes() - 30);
const queryString = `"FILTERS" newer:${Math.round(ThirtyMinutesAgo.getTime()/1000)}`
const threads = GmailApp.search(queryString); // threads the last 30 minutes
```

This approach is more efficient for two reasons:

1. You have less data (threads) to iterate over with the `for` loop.
2. You don't need to apply and `if` statement on every thread.

**Solution:**

```
function getDetails(){
  var DEST_URL = "SHEET_URL"; //redacted for sensitivity
  var DEST_SHEETNAME = "Test";
  
  var destss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(DEST_URL);
  var destSheet = destss.getSheetByName(DEST_SHEETNAME);
  
//  var threads = GmailApp.search("FILTERS"); //filter settings redacted for sensitivity
  
  // new code
  var ThirtyMinutesAgo = new Date(); 
  ThirtyMinutesAgo.setMinutes(ThirtyMinutesAgo.getMinutes() - 30);
  const queryString = `"FILTERS" newer:${Math.round(ThirtyMinutesAgo.getTime()/1000)}`
  const threads = GmailApp.search(queryString); // threads the last 30 minutes
  //

  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();  
    for(var j =0; j < 1; j++){ //only take first message in thread
      var message = messages[j];
      var subject = message.getSubject() ;
      var sentTimeStamp = message.getDate();

          var delimitString = subject.split("is sent");
          var detailName = delimitString[0];

          var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
          destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1).setValue(detailName);
          destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,2),setValue(sentTimeStamp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marios thanks for sharing a more efficient way to do this!

Currently my query string has a filter for sender and text in subject (e.g. "from:abc@gmail.com AND subject:email check").  I read that with time, i have to put an "after:" syntax in it.  Will that still work with what you have shared?

Comment: yes! it will work hundred percent. you can put your current selection and then use the addition that I mentioned @lyk.

Comment: you can do something like: const queryString = old + ` newer:${Math.round(ThirtyMinutesAgo.getTime()/1000)}` where `old` is your current selection @lyk

Answer (score 1):

### You can convert `timeStamp` into ms seconds and then compare to the value of "30 s ago"

Sample:

```js
      var sentTimeStamp = message.getDate();
      var now = new Date();
      var ThirtyMinutesAgo = now-30*60*1000;
      if(sentTimeStamp.getTime() < ThirtyMinutesAgo){
        ...
      }
```

References:

- [newDate()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)
- [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Answer (score 0):

I tried @marios answer but its no luck for me so I made my own solution for filter with date using slice method which worked.

```
var targetEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
  var timeWindow = 30; // Time window in minutes
  
  var date = new Date();
  var startTime = new Date(date.getTime() - (timeWindow * 60000)); // Convert minutes to milliseconds
  
var threads = GmailApp.search('after:' + startTime.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  Logger.log("Size "+threads.length);
```